# SQL Query to Find Mis-Matching Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a local User table which gets it's data from our client.  Once a week, they will supply us with an updated version of their user data.  We then need to feed any new users into our User table (that's easy), plus update any existing users with any new data (this is where I'm stuck).

So, let's say our local table is called UserLocal, and then we have a table that gets wiped out and re-written once a week with the new data from the client called UserNew.  The columns, with a sample of one user, looks like this:

```
UserLocal

UserId    UserCode    FirstName    LastName
12345     ABC         John         Doe
```

But, the new data feed from the client looks like this:

```
UserNew

UserId    UserCode    FirstName    LastName
12345     XYZ         John         Doe
```

So, the UserCode for John has changed.  What I'm trying to do is write a query that finds all rows in UserNew where the UserId matches a row in UserLocal, but the UserCode does not match.

Having a hard time with that syntax.

Comment: Is `UserId`  primary key in both tables? Show DDL please.

Comment: It is not set as a primary key, but the value is unique

Comment: You have sn.Student_ID_Number = sn.Student_ID_Number in your query above - hence the multiple rows :-) Should it be sn.Student_ID_Number = s.Student_ID_Number ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM UserNew n
    JOIN UserLocal l
        ON l.UserId = n.UserId
        AND l.UserCode != n.UserCode
```

Comment: Yeah that was the first thing I tried.  It doesn't get the job done. It runs for 30+ seconds and returns thousands of duplicate rows.  Seems logical, but doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure you only have one record for each user in each table?

Comment: I just checked.  Yes.  Unique rows per user in both tables.

Comment: So there is only one row per user (UserId) in each table, but the query above returns thousands of duplicates?  I think we need to see some more representative sample data to attempt to answer this question.

Comment: Then how above query can return any duplicate rows?

Comment: See the screen shot I added to the OP.  (I will have to delete that screen shot when I get this resolved.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `MERGE` command. It's used to update or insert records into a table exactly as you need.

There are plenty of examples on the internet and details of the command can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Comment: Ok thanks BHS.  I will get to the point eventually where I merge the data. Right now I just need to be able to see how many rows are going to be merged, and which rows they are.

Comment: The merge is easy to write - the OUTPUT clause can also give you the details of inserts and updates

Comment: another good example here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Is there a way to output the possible results without committing them?

Comment: If you know you want to update records already there and insert new ones why wouldn't you commit ? Wrap it in a transaction I guess ? Are you executing from SSMS ?

Comment: See follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957995/write-a-merge-statement-for-mis-matching-values

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see and/or track changes prior to MERGE

```
Declare @UserLocal table (UserId int,UserCode varchar(50),FirstName varchar(50),LastName varchar(50))
Insert Into @UserLocal values (12345,'ABC','John','Doe')

Declare @UserNew table (UserId int,UserCode varchar(50),FirstName varchar(50),LastName varchar(50))
Insert Into @UserNew values (12345,'XYZ','Johnnny','Doe')

Declare @XML xml
Set @XML = (Select * From (Select Ver=0,* from @UserLocal Union All Select Ver=1,* from @UserNew) A for XML RAW)
;with cteBase as (
    Select UserId       = r.value('@UserId','int') 
          ,Ver          = r.value('@Ver','int')
          ,Item         = Attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(max)')
          ,Value        = Attr.value('.','varchar(max)')
    From @XML.nodes('/row') AS A(r)
    Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*[local-name(.)!="Ver"]') AS B(Attr)
)
,cteExt as (Select *,LastValue =Lag(Value) over (Partition By UserID,Item Order by Ver) From cteBase)
Select UserID
      ,Item
      ,Before=LastValue
      ,After =Value
 From  cteExt 
 Where Value<>LastValue and LastValue is not null
 Order By UserID,Item
```

Returns

```
UserID  Item        Before  After
12345   FirstName   John    Johnnny
12345   UserCode    ABC     XYZ
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge or three DML statements..

```
Insert into localtable
        select * from clienttable ct 
        where  not exists(select 1 from localtable t where t.userid=ct.userid)

--delete..not exists also can be used

delete  lc
from
localtable lc
join
clinettable ct
on ct.userid<>lc.userid


---update

;With cte
as
(
select * from clienttable
except 
select * from localtbale
)
update lc
set lc.usercode=c.usercode
--do for all columns
set
from
localtable lc
join cte c
on c.userid=lc.userid
```