# Write a MERGE Statement for mis-matching values

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I have a table, tblstars_new, which is updated weekly from the client.  I have another table, tblstars, which needs to import new and updated data from tblstars_new.

Finding rows in tblstars_new that do not exist in tblstars, and then adding then to tblstars is simple.

But, I also need to find rows in tblstars_new in which the column PandA_Code has changed, and then update the identical row in tblstars.

This query tells me which rows from tblstars_new have PandA_Code's that have changed and need to be updated in tblstars.

```
SELECT 
    sn.*
FROM
    tblstars_new sn
    JOIN tblstars s ON sn.Student_ID_Number = s.Student_ID_Number AND sn.PandA_Code != s.PandA_Code
```

I'm trying to figure out a MERGE statement that will make the changes. As I'm doing in Prod, I can't really play around.  Two questions:

1) Is it possible to see the changes without actually doing them?

2) Is the MERGE statement below correct?

```
BEGIN TRAN;
MERGE tblstars AS T         -- Target
USING tblstars_new AS S     -- Source
ON 
    (T.Student_ID_Number = S.Student_ID_Number AND T.PandA_Code != S.PandA_Code) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN 
    UPDATE SET T.PandA_Code = S.PandA_Code
OUTPUT $action;
ROLLBACK TRAN;
GO
```

Comment: Take a backup of both tables and save them with new names then do your testing. I would hope that it wouldnt cause too much of an issue and is 100 times safer.

Comment: ~I think just switching your WHEN NOT MATCHED to WHEN MATCHED may well work but have not tested

Comment: If the @sboahra's answer is solved your problem what about `which needs to import new and updated data from tblstars_new.` What about the **new**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply done by using join instead of merge statement:

```
UPDATE T SET T.PandA_Code = S.PandA_Code FROM tblstart T 
INNER JOIN tblstars_new P ON P.Student_ID_Number = T.Student_ID_Number
WHERE T.PandA_Code <> S.PandA_Code
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the `MERGE` query that satisfy your requests.

```
BEGIN TRAN;
MERGE tblstars AS T         -- Target
USING tblstars_new AS S     -- Source
ON T.Student_ID_Number = S.Student_ID_Number -- They shoudl match by PK
WHEN MATCHED AND  AND T.PandA_Code != S.PandA_Code
    THEN                    -- when matched and PandA_Code different update them
    UPDATE SET T.PandA_Code = S.PandA_Code
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET -- When not matched by TARGET (there is in source but not in target)
    THEN INSERT (<field1, field2, ...>)  
        VALUES (<S.field1, S.filed2, ...>)  -- then insert them
OUTPUT deleted.*, $action, inserted.* INTO #TheTempTable; 
SELECT * FROM #TheTempTable;  -- here you can see the cnages and rollback if something is wrong
ROLLBACK TRAN;
GO
```